# Difference in location between google maps and jquery google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

Why there is a difference in locations when using [jquery mobile maps api](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map) compared to [google maps](https://maps.google.co.in/).

Here are the images showing the difference

Locations as in *google map*

[image]

Locations when using *[jquery ui maps api](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map)*

[image]

Here are the lat longs i am testing with

+39° 44' 41.22", -104° 49' 54.15"

+39° 44' 39.28", -104° 50' 5.86"

There are other lat longs where i am getting the difference.

The JS library i am using - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=geometry

[Demo Code](https://gist.github.com/3205645)

How to solve this?

Pointers?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include code showing **exactly** how you are specifying the ends of the route in the API?

Comment: @AndrewLeach updated the question with demo application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has problems with geocoding strings representing coordinates, which I think is because the reverse-geocoder gets involved. Since you have the coordinates, you can use those to create `LatLng` objects directly, which seems to work.

```
{ 'origin': new google.maps.LatLng(39.744783, -104.831709), 
  'destination': new google.maps.LatLng(39.744244, -104.834960), 
  'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING }
```

Using those co-ordinates gets closer to the stated destination than Google Maps does, but (because it's closer) it uses a different route to get there.

http://jsfiddle.net/zqtJJ/

If you want the route to use E 17th Place to get to that building, you'll need to specify the destination as being a little closer to the street than the footpath.